# print a list of valid log file entries in python 3 regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, list, iteration, match

I am new in python. I want to open a file logs.txt and match all the ip address in every line (log entry).

I would then print the number/count of log entries with an IP address.
what I have so far:

```
import re
#read the file
file = open("logile.txt")
lineList = []
for line in file:
    match = re.search( r'^\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}', line )
    if match:
        print("IP found in this line is:  ", match.group())
```

Now I want to print the number of log entries with this IP addresses. How do I append every line with an IP to my lineList and print the count?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: The last line of my post @DYZ

Comment: I have Edited 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
file = open("logfile.txt")
lineList = []
count = 0
for ln, line in enumerate(file):
    match = re.search( r'^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b', line )
    if match:
        count += 1
        print("Match #{}: IP found in line {} is: {}".format(count, ln+1, match.group()))
        lineList.append(match.group())
```

Note the additional backslashes and the [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) in your regex to prevent false matches. Also, because of the `^` anchor, the regex will only match IP addresses at the start of a line.

Comment: hey @Tim ther is an error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax - lineList.append(match.group())

Comment: Ah yes, the previous line was missing a `)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive lookahead to assert if the IP is present in a line:

```
(?=.*\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}.*).+
```

Explanation:

`(?=...)` - positive lookahead

`.*` - match zero or more of any characters

`\d{1,3}` - match 1 up to three digits

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`\.\d{1,3}` - match dot literally and one up to three digits

`(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}` - match `\.\d{1,3}` three times

If assertion is true, then match whole line with `.+`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Hb25J/1)